# How should I takcle the following problem?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

How should I takcle the following problem?

$x$, $y$ and $a$ are integers

$a$ is known

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y \leq x \\ 
y =  \frac a x \\ 
y > 0, x > 0, a > 0 \\
x - y \rightarrow min
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

It was easy to draw the respective graphic in Desmos:

[image]

Now I think I need to find the minimum of the $x - y$ in the highlighted on the screenshot area. I was thinking about taking a derivative and setting it to $0$, but I do not know how to proceed further.

I remember from the university that there are methods to solve such min/max problems. Could someone direct me towards a solution for the problem, please?

Comment: I can not recollect how the math styler is called, so I was not able to present the equation well formatted. It was called something like Lex, could you remind me, please, how it was called? I would format my question well then.

Comment: The formatter is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: It's called MathJax, and you've basically used it, but instead of ```<=``` you should type ```\ge```. Does:$$x-y->min$$mean that you want to find the minimum of $x-y$?

Comment: @Joe, yes. I want to find minimum with the conditions presented above.

Comment: Aparently you are restricted to integers. If $a$ is given, then you want $x$ to be the smallest divisor of $a$ greater than or equal to $\sqrt{a}$, and $y=\frac{a}{x}$ so $x-y=x-\frac{a}{x}=\frac{x^2-a}{x}$

Comment: $\sqrt[2]{-a}$, $-\sqrt[2]{-a}$ are the roots of the derivative of the $\frac {x^2-a} {x}$. Could you, please, help by directing me what to do next?

Comment: @Henry, so, finding the $x$ and $y$ (given that finding a square root to an integer accuracy requires $O(1)$ time) would require at least the $O(\sqrt a)$ time complexity, because we would need to iterate over all possible values. Am I right?

Comment: @Henry, just like here: https://dilyar85.gitbooks.io/leetcode-solutions-with-analysis/content/Problems/492_construct_the_rectangle_java.html? I was just hoping for a mathematical solution to produce an $O(1)$ time complexity.

Comment: Your link does not specify the answers have to be integers.  If they can be real values, or if $a$ is a square, then the answer is simply $x=y=\sqrt{a}$

Comment: @Henry, sorry for not being explicit. The `int[]` return type means that the result should be an integer pair.

Comment: @Henry, btw. Funny that I remember your nickname. 3-4 years ago I had a different account (I lost a password to it) and I remember you helping me with a question (I do not remember which one exactly). Thank you for continuing to do the good work. Oh God, time passes so fast. :)